# How to portforward on fritzbox 6320

Tags: internet, port-forwarding, fritzbox

I'm trying to port forward my second router but it seams to does not word on my fritz box here ( on picture) is how I did it, but when I enter my wanip:port I cant access that page, any help ? Cheers

[image: FritzBox Port Forward]

Comment: Does your ISP assigned you a public ip address or a private ip address?  Update your question, if its a private ip address, you won't be able to forward external traffic to your device and within your own lan network it isn't required.  You also have UPnP enabled, so technically, you shouldn't have to port forward anything anyways

Comment: My ip is 10.151.116.83 so its private so thank you

Comment: You will be unable to forward external traffic to your device in that case.

Comment: Your ISP is likely using [Carrier Grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT). Please read [Alternatives to Port Forwarding & NAT](http://portforward.com/help/alt-to-pf.htm): "There are four major problems that you may run into that would require alternatives to port forwarding. " ...